# SwiftUI TabView Embedded In Another View Problem

Tags: swift, view, swiftui, tabview

For a few time now, I have been playing with SwiftUI. I'd like to make it clear that I do have a Java and JS background, but no any Swift experience.

So the idea is:
I'd like to have a view (referred later on as **main view**) where the screen is divided into two parts (views). The top one will be used just like a header - picture with maybe a footer (the frosted footer in the screenshots).
Then the second part of the screen I want it to be another View that is actually a TabView. See attached screenshots of [unscrolled view of the main view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPStu.jpg) and
[scrolled view of the main view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clOor.png)

Currently, what I have now is:

```
struct CarDetailsView: View {
    let car: Car
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            HeadingView(car: car)
            CarDescriptionView(car: car)
                .offset(y: -36)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Which works fine (as in the screenshots), where **HeadingView** is the picture with the footer, and then **CarDescriptionView** is the "second" view of the screen with the description. This is also the part that I'd like to make it TabView.

I thought, I can just wrap the **CarDescription** View inside a TabView, just like that:

```
struct CarDetailsView: View {
    let car: Car
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            HeadingView(car: car)
            TabView {
                CarDescriptionView(car: car)
                    .offset(y: -36)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Description", systemImage: "car")
                    }
            }
            
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

However, then I am getting this thing happening [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7rl1.jpg)

Note, the structure of my other View are:

```
struct HeadingView: View {
    
    var car: Car
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("25 300EUR")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
                .padding(.horizontal, 12)
                .padding(.vertical, 4)
                .background(Color.init(hexadecimal: "66B054"))
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottomLeading)
                .padding(16)
            
            
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "car")//todo: make logo go here
                    .padding(.leading, 16)
                    .padding(.trailing, 16)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                    Text("\(car.make) \(car.model)")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .bold()
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(String(car.odometer / 1000))k km  |")
                            .font(.caption)
                        Text("\(String(car.year))  |")
                            .font(.caption)
                        Text("\(String(car.engine.horsepower))bhp  |")
                            .font(.caption)
                        Text("20km away")
                            .font(.caption)
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.top, 12)
            .padding(.bottom, 38)
            .background(
                VisualEffectBlurView(blurStyle: .systemThinMaterialDark)
            )
            
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 500, maxHeight: 500)
        .background(
            Image(car.images[0])
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        )
        .mask(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0, style: .continuous)
        )
    }
}
```

and

```
struct CarDescriptionView: View {
    let car: Car
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Description")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
                .padding(.top, 32)
                .padding(.leading, 16)
                .padding(.bottom, 16)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            
            Text(car.description)
                .font(.body)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            
            Text(car.description + "\n")
                .font(.body)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            Text(car.description + "\n")
                .font(.body)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            Text(car.description + "\n")
                .font(.body)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            Text(car.description + "\n")
                .font(.body)
                .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .background(.white)
        .mask(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous)
        )
    }
}
```

Please note that I have also tried to place the TabView inside the **CarDetailsView**, but again with the same result.
Changing the **ScrollView** to **VStack** in the **main component** results in somewhat working view. However, then I do not get any scrolling of the header View (the car image), but only I am able to scroll within the tabbed view.

As I said at the beginning, I am really new to this, so I am not even sure if the concept is correct or not.